# Why sessionStorage not update the page in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, session-storage

I am implementing a basic login in react, however when the token is saved in sessionStorage the page does not refresh normally like when I do it with hooks.

I use this component to save and return the token when the login is correct.

```
//UseToken.js
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function useToken() {
  const getToken = () => {
    const tokenString = sessionStorage.getItem('token');
    const userToken = JSON.parse(tokenString);
    return userToken
  };

  const [token, setToken] = useState(getToken());

  const saveToken = userToken => {
    sessionStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(userToken));
    setToken(userToken.token);
  };

  return {
    setToken: saveToken,
    token
  }
}
```

Later, in the app component, I ask for the status of the token in order to render either the login view or the application view.

```
//App.js
const {token, setToken} = useToken();

  if(!token) {
    return <Login setToken={setToken} />
  }
```

Then the token is saved in sessionStorage, however the login is still rendered.

Help

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that, when you set the token, you set it as a non-existent object instead of just passing the value to it.

```
const saveToken = userToken => {
   sessionStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(userToken));
   setToken(userToken); // instead of userToken.token
 };
```